# "This device is not working" message in "Additional Drivers" in Asus zenbook Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, asus, iwlwifi, ubuntu-drivers

The title is self explanatory, basically, when I go to a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04's Additional Drivers I'm seeing this:

[image: Printscreen]

I have been searching online and tried two things:

- Disable "fast startup" on my windows (installed as dualboot)
- Downloaded and copied to `/lib/firmware/` the "Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265" drivers in [this link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)

However, the issue persists. My internet seems to work fine so far, although sometimes after hibernation, it does not connect to very specific networks and I need to restart my laptop. I think I have everything updated as my kernel (as seen in the output of `uname -a`) is `5.3.0-28-generic`.

Any ideas of what else I can do? I admit I don't have much practice with dealing with drivers in linux.

Comment: This an instance of the following Launchpad bug: [software-properties-gtk erroneously reports that Intel Wireless-AC 9260 device is not working](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1859308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A launchpad bug was submitted to for this issue with `software-properties-gtk` (Software & Updates GUI). 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1859308

If you login to Launchpad.net, and claim the bug affects you, you can raise the bug heat. The higher the bug heat, the more attention the bug receives. 
https://blog.launchpad.net/bug-tracking/bug-heat

I have this issue on two separate computers, Dell Precession 7520 running clean 19.10 and OnLogic Karbon 300 running 18.04. Both computers WiFi and Bluetooth are working perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, if you subscribe to notifications you can also raise the heat!